# Subsequently add tasks to a task, but limit the number of parallel executed ones

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, async-await

I have severe performance problems, i.e. four cores running on 100%, blocking everything else, when I want to show thumbnails in a grid containing more than 10k entries.
There is an event that fires when a line is shown to the user, which loads the image. In this event an instance of `GridImageManager` is called with `AddAndStartLoading`. When I scroll down, this event is fired too often and my cores are flooded with threads.

I tried to rewrite the code, using Callbacks and a list of still to load cells, but the list is not threadsafe, leading to Exceptions, when I want to remove an element, that has already been removed from another thread.

Then I tried to use semaphores, but with them I can not realize the `WaitForLoadingCompleted`-method, because I can not access the amount of free resources.

I also read into Tasks, but could not get how they would help me.

My constraints are the following:

- Loading images must start immediately, after the first call of `AddAndStartLoading`.
- No more than `N` loading processes should be executed at any time.
- Subsequent calls to `AddAndStartLoading` may wait, but should be processed as soon as the amount of loading processes drops below `N`.
- `WaitForLoadingCompleted` should wait for all Loading threads to be finished, while on the other hand allowing to do `Application.DoEvents()`. I can not refactor this at the moment.

What patterns/strategies do I have to use to accomplish this?

To give you an idea: This is my first attempt. It works up to the point where `CellsToLoad` gets empty.

```
public class GridImageManager
{

    public GridImageManager()
    {
        CellsToLoad = new List<(UltraGridCell cell, ImageLoader loader)>();
        LoadingCells = new Dictionary<UltraGridCell, ImageLoader>();
    }

    public delegate void ImageLoader(object obj);

    private List<(UltraGridCell cell, ImageLoader loader)> CellsToLoad { get; set; }

    private Dictionary<UltraGridCell, ImageLoader> LoadingCells { get; set; }

    public void AddCellToLoad(UltraGridCell cell, ImageLoader loader)
    {
        CellsToLoad.Add((cell, loader));

        StartLoading();
    }

    private void CallbackImageLoaded(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        if (ar.AsyncState is UltraGridCell cell)
        {
            LoadingCells.Remove(cell);
            StartLoading();
        }
    }

    private void StartLoading()
    {
        if (LoadingCells.Count >= 10)
            return;

        if (CellsToLoad.Count == 0)
            return;

        var next = CellsToLoad.First();
        CellsToLoad.Remove(next);

        LoadingCells.Add(next.cell, next.loader);

        next.loader.BeginInvoke(null, CallbackImageLoaded, next.cell);
    }

    public void WaitForLoadingCompleted()
    {
        while (CellsToLoad.Count > 0 && LoadingCells.Count > 0)
        {
            Application.DoEvents(); // Can't refactor this right now
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have this baked into my clipboard these days: https://www.wintellect.com/tasks-are-still-not-threads-and-async-is-not-parallel/

Comment: `Application.DoEvents();` is very suspicious

Comment: I have read this 3 times and still confused. `I also read into Tasks, but could not get how they would help me` Well this says to me you need to read about them some more. Also `async` and `await`, and `SemaphoreSlim`

Comment: @JohnB, this is one of the links I read. Still chewing on it.

Comment: @TheGeneral, SemaphoreSlim does indeed look promising.

Comment: Yeah id experiment with all this outside of your main application to get you handle on what you can do with async await, tasks ect. also SemaphoreSlim is the goto for a concurrency limiter in async pattern